# Add captcha to registration form

Tags: users, captcha

I'm quite familiar with PHP but do not a clue of Drupal.
All I have to do is to add a captcha to the registration form. How do I do this and btw. where is this registration form module located.

I know that this a beginner's question, but nevertheless any help would be appreciated. :)

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Hello. Can I assume you have seen https://drupal.org/project/captcha ? Any problems with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CAPTCHA](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module. To add captcha in in drupal registration form there is no need to edit any single line of code. First you download and install the module then go to module settings page (**/admin/user/captcha/captcha/settings**) and enable the captcha for user registration form.

Comment: Ok, made it half way: I downloaded, installed and activated the captcha module. But how can I enable this module for the user registration form?

Comment: If you are using drupal 6 then:
Go to: **http://yoursite.com/admin/user/captcha/captcha/settings**
OR
for drupal 7 :
Go to: **http://d7_test1.com/#overlay=admin/config/people/captcha**

Here you can enable captcha for user registration form.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Captcha Module](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) for this.

> A CAPTCHA is a challenge-response test most often placed within web forms to determine whether the user is human. The purpose of CAPTCHA is to block form submissions by spambots, which are automated scripts that post spam content everywhere they can. The CAPTCHA module provides this feature to virtually any user facing web form on a Drupal site.

For more configuration detail of the module go through the READMe.txt.